# Problemas con importar excel desde php

Tags: php

Utilizando este código me descarga el archivo me muestras los datos pero algunos registros no salen en las celdas que corresponde por ejemplo el nombre sale en la celda de apellido

SALUDOS

```
 <?php
  /*******EDIT LINES 3-8*******/
  $DB_Server = "localhost"; //MySQL Server    
  $DB_Username = "pcomp"; //MySQL Username     
  $DB_Password = "KneTPuxJ77f4YLNX";             //MySQL Password     
  $DB_DBName = "base";         //MySQL Database Name  
  $DB_TBLName = "tabla"; //MySQL Table Name   
  $filename = "ad";         //File Name
  /*******YOU DO NOT NEED TO EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE*******/    
  //create MySQL connection   

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM $DB_TBLName";

   $Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or 
   die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . 
   mysql_errno());
   //select database   
   $Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select 
   database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());
   //execute query 
   $result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query: 
   <br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());
   $file_ending = "xls";
   //header info for browser
   header("Content-Type: application/xls");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");
   header("Pragma: no-cache");
   header("Expires: 0");
   /*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
   //define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
   $sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
   //start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
   for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
    echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
    }
    print("\n");
    //end of printing column names  
     //start while loop to get data
     while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
    $schema_insert = "";
    for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result))
    {
        if(!isset($row[$j]))
            $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($row[$j] != "")
            $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
        else
            $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
   // $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", 
   $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\n";
    print(trim($schema_insert));
    print "\r";
   }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

En este `for` no estás incrementando la variable `j` que sirve para recorrer los campos:

```
for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result))
```

Debería quedar así:

```
for ($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result); $j++)
```